# Google Cloud Streaming Speech API C# not working

Tags: c#, api, google-api, cloud, speech

I was trying to read streaming speech from microphone and translate it to text using Google Cloud Speech API sample code provided in the following URL.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api

I followed the steps provided along with code and was able to enable speech service, got the API key from google account and finally was also able to build the solution but when i run project .exe file in console it was throwing exception
related to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environmental variable setup.

Then to fix this error i have added the following code

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"D:\Project-b1145200231e.json");
```

inside the main method of Recognize.cs file

This fixed the exception but the execution gets stopped/hanged after reading the following code.

```
Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                    default(CancellationToken)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.Results)
                    {
                        foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please help on this. Thanks.